# CSS Float Left and Right with Any Order HTML Elements and No Gaps

Tags: css, css-float

Is it possible for (and how can) HTML elements float left and right, stacking in perfectly no matter what HTML tag order they are in, just top-down with all the float: lefts stacked on the left, and all the float: rights stacked on the right, with no gaps?

(preferably, with the cleanest most standard CSS practices, no absolute positioning scripts with javascript etc.)

In other words, with this example, with the HTML elements being in order, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, the left col would have 1, 3, 5, 6 floated left, and 2, 4, 7, 8 floating right, in regularly spaced elements, no white gaps.

```
I want results like this layout:

|  1  2  |
|  3  4  |
|  5  7  |
|  6  8  |

Instead, I'm getting results like this layout:

|  1  2  |
|  3  4  |
|  5     |
|  6  7  |
|     8  |
```

Here's the basic HTML/CSS code example:

```
<html>

 <style>

  .lefties, .righties {

   width: 40%;
   height: 100px;
   background: #DEF;
   float: left;
   clear: left;

  } 

  .righties { 

   background-color: #FED;
   float:right;
   clear:right; 

  }



  </style>

  <div id="container">

   <div class="lefties" >Test 1</div>
   <div class="righties">Test 2</div>
   <div class="lefties" >Test 3</div>
   <div class="righties">Test 4</div>
   <div class="lefties" >Test 5</div>
   <div class="lefties" >Test 6</div>
   <div class="righties">Test 7</div>
   <div class="righties">Test 8</div>

  </div>

</html>
```

Comment: Note: 5 and 6 are purposely sequential in the HTML, as are 7 and 8.

Thanks

Comment: The idea / challenge here is to stack them as just tags in the same container, not with 2 column DIVs (left and right) to separate them, as most layouts would do to get 2 columns created.

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got a solution that involves absolute positioning. According to W3.org, there's something called [`toggle()`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-values/#toggle-notation) in the works.

For now, we're stuck with this mess:

```
<html>
<body>

<style>

.lefties, .righties{
  top: 10px;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

.lefties {
  background: #DEF;
  left: 10px;
}

.righties { 
  background-color: #FED;
  right: 10px;
}

.lefties ~ .lefties,
.righties ~ .righties{
  transform: translate(0px, 100px);
}

.lefties ~ .lefties ~ .lefties,
.righties ~ .righties ~ .righties{
  transform: translate(0px, 200px);
}

.lefties ~ .lefties ~ .lefties ~ .lefties,
.righties ~ .righties ~ .righties ~ .righties{
  transform: translate(0px, 300px);
}

.lefties ~ .lefties ~ .lefties ~ .lefties ~ .lefties,
.righties ~ .righties ~ .righties ~ .righties ~ .righties{
  transform: translate(0px, 400px);
}

.lefties ~ .lefties ~ .lefties ~ .lefties ~ .lefties ~ .lefties,
.righties ~ .righties ~ .righties ~ .righties ~ .righties ~ .righties{
  transform: translate(0px, 500px);
}
</style>

<div id="container">
  <div class="lefties" >Test 1</div>
  <div class="righties">Test 2</div>
  <div class="lefties" >Test 3</div>
  <div class="righties">Test 4</div>
  <div class="lefties" >Test 5</div>
  <div class="lefties" >Test 6</div>
  <div class="lefties" >Test 7</div>
  <div class="righties">Test 8</div>
  <div class="righties">Test 9</div>
  <div class="righties">Test 10</div>
  <div class="lefties" >Test 11</div>
  <div class="righties">Test 12</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

But with `toggle()`, it looks like we could clean the .lefties ~ .lefties ~ .lefties ~ ... up to look like this:

```
.lefties ~ .lefties,
.righties ~ .righties{
    transform: translate(0px, toggle(100px,200px,300px,400px,...));
}
```

Comment: Is there perhaps a way to do it without clears then?

With "clear: none" and some other CSS trickery?...

Comment: It may be possible, but I don't know. I only know for-sure that it's impossible with floats and clears. I am going to play with this for a while and see if I can come up with anything though.

Comment: hey OG Sean, for your own reference.. when you get answers like the one above (which clearly shows that it took some time to compose) and you still don't give any vote ups etc (even if it doesn't fully answer your question) it discourages other people from contributing.. well placed effort should be rewarded. I'm voting this one up. There is a difference between voting up a question and awarding it the correct answer.

Comment: Yeah I left the office before it was posted.  When I left the answer was different, also. I just returned.  Sorry if 12 hours isn't fast enough.  Thanks for sharing this method, I've definitely never seen that approach before.  Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I have my days where I think outside-of-the-box. It doesn't seem to be a realistic approach without toggle, but if there was a way to count the number of "lefties" or "righties" before itself, it'd be a simple `calc()`. I was thinking of `position: relative;` and setting the "lefties" or "righties" height to 0, but with nothing inside of the div to maintain the height, it proved impractical. If you were able to put a div immediately inside of the "lefties" or "righties" and give it a height of 100px, this might be more-easily possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not if all the DIVs are different heights, this will happen.

If they are all the same height you should be fine, other than that i would recommend having 2 container divs and have your divs as children of them.

Comment: Creating two columns to float left and right and adding children to them is the way most people do this, but the question is, can it be done with just elements in any order without column containers.

Comment: Also notice in the CSS the heights are all in fact set to 100px and they still leave a gap in the right col where 5 and 6 are sequential on the left.